# Composite Key join in SQL Error

Tags: sql, postgresql, hive, hql

I an trying to join two tables with two keys. The join code is like:

```
select 
    col1, col2, col3, col4
from 
    data a 
join
    data1 b on a.col1 = b.col1 and a.col3 = b.col3
```

I am getting error:

> Query Error: Error: ER_NON_UNIQ_ERROR: Column 'col1' in field list is ambiguous

```
CREATE TABLE data 
(
    Id Serial,
    col1 VARCHAR(70) NOT NULL,
    col3 varchar(70),
    col2 integer,
    PRIMARY KEY(Id)
);

CREATE TABLE data1 
(
    Id Serial,
    col1 VARCHAR(70) NOT NULL,
    col3 varchar(70),
    col4 integer,
    PRIMARY KEY(Id)
);
```

[SQL fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3kMvTawFgeumTRwWJXkZo4/0) with sample data

Answer (score 3):

It's ambiguous because postgres wants to know which table you want `col1` from.

Add an alias to the fields in the select clause. E.g. select a.col1...